# Selenium WebDriverException: Can't load the profile

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I can't figure out why exactly selenium throws this exception because this construction worked fine before I put it in `while` loop and exception handler.

```
def parse(self, response):
    phrases = self.get_search_phrases()

    for phrase in phrases:
        while True:
            try:
                proxy = urlparse(self.proxies.pop(0))
                fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
                fp.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
                fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http", proxy.scheme + '://' + proxy.netloc)
                fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", proxy.port)
                fp.update_preferences()
                self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
                self.driver.get(BASE_URL)
                input_ = self.driver.find_element_by_id('name')
                button = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#form_person_search button')
                input_.send_keys(phrase)
                button.click()
                sleep(3)
            except (NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException,):
                continue
            else:
                break
```

Comment: You have an extra comma in your except statement.

Comment: What firefox and selenium versions are you using? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe, last versions. I tried updating selenium and FF because I've already encountered similar exception when selenium package in my virtualenv was outdated.